connectivityManager.activeNetwork is null with device in energy saving
in this scenario connectivityManager.activeNetwork is null:

App closed
Push received
Energy saving enabled
connectivityManager.activeNetwork = null

If energy saving is disabled connectivityManager.activeNetwork isn't null.
How can I fix?
